# SQL equivalent of Java code

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate an ID as the first 32 bits being Unix timestamp value and the next 32 bits being the sequence number. The Java equivalent of it would be

```
tID  = (long) timeMinutes << 32 | sequence & 0xFFFFFFFFL; // Upper 32 bits are the Unix minutes lower 32 are the sequence number
```

I am trying to create this ID in SQL so that I can support an upsert. Since Oracle is limited to bitAND I am using bitAND() to create the SQL equivalent of the above. 
The bitwise OR using bitAND is produced as

```
x + y - bitand(x,y)

x = timeMinutes << 32 = trunc((cast(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(systimestamp) as date) - to_date('1-1-1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS'))*24*3600) * power(2,32)
y = sequenceNumber & 0xFFFFFFFFL = bitAND(sequenceNumber,?)
```

I am at a loss as to what the equivalent mask for the sequence number (The question mark in the last expression) will be.

Comment: Seems to me you need a unique identifier out of oracle, isn't that what ORA_ROWSCN was intended for with row dependencies enabled at the table level? Why reinvent the wheel?http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm  or am I missing why you're doing this?

Comment: I asked why we are using this instead of just a sequence. We have partitions based on time and I was told that it is beneficial to have this instead of just a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring why you're doing this for now, `0xFFFFFFFFL` is 2^32 - 1, so you could use:

```
bitand(sequence, power(2, 32) - 1)
```

Using a fixed epoch time of:

```
Tue Sep  8 19:18:45 BST 2015
1441736325
```

... and made up sequence value of 2549626543, your Java code generates:

```
x:   6192210365330227200
y:   2549626543
tID: 6192210367879853743
```

Demo Oracle code:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  x number;
  y number;
  tID number;
begin
  x := 1441736325 * power(2, 32);
  y := bitand(2549626543, power(2, 32) - 1);
  tID := x + y - bitand(x, y);

  dbms_output.put_line('x:   ' || x);
  dbms_output.put_line('y:   ' || y);  
  dbms_output.put_line('tID: ' || tID);  
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

x:   6192210365330227200
y:   2549626543
tID: 6192210367879853743
```

... gets the same output.

Using a sequence value higher than 2^32, e.g. 92549626543, also yields the same; from Java:

```
x:   6192210365330227200
y:   2355313327
tID: 6192210367685540527
```

From Oracle:

```
x:   6192210365330227200
y:   2355313327
tID: 6192210367685540527
```

---

As @Sentinel pointed out, `bitand(x, y)` will always be zero, as `x` only has the first 32 bits, and `y` only has the second 32 bits - so there is no overlap. So you can drop that part and just do:

```
tID := x + y;
```

Or in longer form now there is no repetition:

```
select ((cast(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as date) - date '1970-01-01')
    * 86400 * power(2,32)) + bitand(:sequence, power(2, 32) - 1)
from dual;
```

or with the same fixed values:

```
select (1441736325 * power(2, 32)) + bitand(2549626543, power(2, 32) - 1)
from dual;
```

The results are the same as above.

Comment: Won't `bitand(x, y)` always be zero?  The low order 32 bits of `X` will always be 0x00000000 due to the left shift operation (`* power(2, 32)`) and the high order bits of `Y` will always be zero due to the `BITAND` operation applied to it on assignment.  As such you should be able assign `X + Y` to `tID` without subtracting the `BITAND` of `X` and `Y`

Comment: True. D'oh. I was copying what the OP said without thinking enough.

Comment: `X + (Y - BITAND(X, Y))` is the general form for performing a bitwise OR when all you have is bitwise AND. The parenthesis around the last two terms ensures that there are no overflow issues encountered during the addition step.  That might not be and issue in oracle, but then again better safe than sorry.